# How to read each line and then find the missing document?

Tags: java, python

Sample Input format:

```
Name of the file,  Author,  format type,  id,  content length.
resume,            abc,     pdf,          7,   90
resume,            asc,     doc,          2,   90
resume,            azc,     docx,         3,   90
```

Output:

Missing document format

```
pdf

2,3

doc

7,3
```

Here is my approach: take input from external txt file(Required).

```
File file = new File("//Users//Downloads//test_cases//input.txt");
ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();//creating new generic arraylist  
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String st;  
  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)                                
    al.add(st);
br.close();
```

So, my question is which is apt data structure to use? After reading each line. also how should i approach in storing data ?
A sample code would be great help. thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you wish to access the data. For example access data in each of the individual row or access them through column wise ?.

Comment: in which language do you require the solution

Comment: Java is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is based on the premise there will be only one value in the entry in the "format type" field.

This solution requires the use of google guava collection. The jars can downloaded from "https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release19"

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;
import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;
public class FileReader {

public void processData() {

Multimap dataMap = readFile();
dataMap.get("format type");
Object[] array =  ((ArrayListMultimap) dataMap).get("format type").toArray();

 System.out.println("Missing formats");
 for (Object entry:array) {
 System.out.println(entry.toString().trim());

 String position= "";
 for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
 if(!entry.toString().equalsIgnoreCase (array[i].toString())) {
 position= position+" "+i;
 }
 }
 System.out.println(position);
 }
 }

  public Multimap readFile() {
  File file = new File("/Users/sree/Desktop/text.txt");
  Multimap<String,String> dataMap =  ArrayListMultimap.create();

  ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();
  BufferedReader br;

  try {
  br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(file));
  Arrays.stream(br.readLine().split(",")).forEach(s ->al.add(s.trim()));
  String st;
  while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {

  VariableIcrementor instance = new VariableIcrementor();
  Arrays.stream(st.split(",")).                                      
  forEach(s->dataMap.put(al.get(instance.increment()),s));
  }
  br.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return dataMap;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
       FileReader instance = new FileReader();
       instance.processData();
    }
}
```

variable incrementor implementation details

```
public class VariableIcrementor {

private int i=0;

public int increment() {
    return i++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use hashmaps to store the data with keys as formats and ids as values. If you want to use python, here's a sample:

```
# Read line from file
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
entries = line.split(' ')
# Hashmap to store formats and corresponding ids
formats = {}
# set to store all the ids
ids = set()
for en in entries:
    vals = en.split(',')
    frmt, identifier = vals[2], vals[3]
    # Set of ids for each format
    if frmt not in formats:
        formats[frmt] = set()
    formats[frmt].add(identifier)
    ids.add(identifier)
print("Missing formats")
for frmt in formats:
    print(frmt)
    # Missing formats are set difference between all the ids and the current ids
    print(ids-formats[frmt])
```